# Upset Plot in Python with large dataset

Tags: python, database, pandas, graph

The Best and efficient way of plotting upset plot in python for large dataset. 
I've three data set consisting of 500Million, 300Million and 150Million. 
I know pyupset can be used but is it recommended to use with above mentioned large dataset.

Comment: By efficiency, do you mean speed? Are you looking for proof (timing, etc), since the upset plot related answer is not chosen?

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this library **pyupset** which can plot Upset Graph given the dataset in Pandas.

```
import pyupset as pyu
dataframe1 = pd.read_csv('some.csv')
dataframe2 = pd.read_csv('some.csv')
data_dict = {'dataframe1 ': dataframe1 ,
         'dataframe2 ': dataframe2 }
graph = pyu.plot(data_dict, unique_keys=['BTN'])
```